# Какое условие должно быть, чтобы это заработало

Tags: javascript

```js
function showRandomNum(min = 0, max) {
    max = document.getElementById('randomNum').value;
    randomNumber = createRandomNum();
    if (typeof (max) === 'number') {
        alert(randomNumber);
    } else {
        alert("Это не число!");
    }   

}   

//Отдельная функция генерации числа

function createRandomNum(min, max) {
    let randomNumber = Math.random() * (max - min ) + min;
    return randomNumber;
}
```

Comment: ничего не понял, что нужно в итоге-то?

Answer (score 1):

Независимо от значения инпута, он всегда будет возвращать строку, поэтому `typeof (max)` всегда дает `string`.

Можно превращать его в число, поставив перед ним один плюсик... `typeof( +max ) === 'number'` — Это тоже криво, потому что если там будет не число, оно превратится в `NaN` - но `typeof NaN` тоже `number`. Хочется тогда добавить условие `+max !== NaN` НЕ равно NaN, но загвоздка, с NaN нельзя ничего сравнивать) Даже `NaN === NaN` дает false.

Поэтому есть специальная функция `isNaN( arg )` Она пробует превратить аргумент в число, и возвращает false, если не было ошибки. Соответственно, в основное условие нужно добавить логическое НЕ `!` — оно превращает false в true, и наоборот.

```js
max = document.getElementById('randomNum');

if ( !isNaN(max.value) ) {
  console.log( createRandomNum(0, +max.value) );
  // Вызов функции тоже был кривой, без аргументов.
} else {
  console.log("Это не число!");
}


function createRandomNum(min, max) {
  // На случай, если функция будет 
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

```html
<input id="randomNum" value="5">
```

P.s. Раз такое дело...

```js
console.log( "[] →    ",  isNaN( [] ),         +[] )        // false
console.log( '"0" →   ',  isNaN( "0" ),        +"0" )       // false
console.log( '"" →    ',  isNaN( "" ),         +"" )        // false
console.log( "null →  ",  isNaN( null ),       +null )      // false
console.log( "false → ",  isNaN( false ),      +false )     // false !!!

console.log( "{} →    ",  isNaN( {} ),         +{} )        // true
console.log( "undef → ",  isNaN( undefined ),  +undefined ) // true
console.log( "NaN →   ",  isNaN( NaN ),        +NaN )       // true
```

Comment: Когда вы уже начнёте дубликаты искать?

Comment: @РустамГимранов А я до сих пор их искал только если попадался совсем уж очевидный 1:1 дубль. Где-то есть описанная официальная позиция сообщества про это? Если закрывают вопрос, он же всё равно остается доступным... что с прямым ответом, что с ссылкой на ответ.